# Animating orthographic scale on a camera, can't select the action in the action editor

Tags: animation, camera, dopesheet

I added some keyframes on the Orthographic Scale property of a camera to add a zoom to a 2D animation, and I can see the action it created in the NLA strip but I can't seem to find it in the Action Editor on the dope sheet when I want to go back and make changes. Is there any way to edit this action?

[image: Sceenshot of my workspace, action I'm tryign to select in the dopesheet highlighted in the NLA Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, figured it out - you can't open it in the Action Editor since it's not an object level action, but you can bring it up in the dopesheet for editing by selecting it in the NLA Editor and hitting Edit->Start Tweaking Strip Actions